# An integral relation of gamma function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function

Let, $s=\sigma+it$. For $\sigma >0$ prove that

$$\int_0^{\infty}x^{\frac s2-1}e^{-n^2\pi x}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(s/2)}{n^s\pi^{s/2}}$$

How can I prove this ? I think it can be prove by complex integration with suitable contour which I've to choose with a suitable complex function. But I'm unable to do that.

Comment: How is the gamma function defined? This is one step away from the definition I’m used to seeing.

Comment: $\displaystyle \Gamma(s)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}x^{s-1}\,dx$

Comment: Compare these two integrals. How could you change one to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
    \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1+s/2}e^{-n^2\pi x}dx \\
     = (n^2\pi)^{-s/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}(n^2\pi x)^{-1+s/2}e^{-(n^2\pi x)}d(n^2\pi x) \\
   = (n^2\pi)^{-s/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-1+s/2}e^{-u}du \\
   = (n^2\pi)^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2).
$$